# Printing json data recieved from php in tabular form in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am receiving data in JSON format for name & email by `$.ajax()` jquery function. I need to put this data in tabular format in a div `('#div1')`. I am unable to do this. Can someone help?

JSON received:

```
[{"jname":"Charles","jemail":"charles@gmail.com"},{"jname":"Bollen","jemail":"bollen@gmail.com"},{"jname":"Sita","jemail":"sita@gmail.com"},{"jname":"Lita","jemail":"lita@gmail.com"},{"jname":"Azma","jemail":"azma@gmail.com"},{"jname":"Robert","jemail":"robert@gmail.com"},{"jname":"Charu","jemail":"charu@gmail.com"}]
```

jQuery Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "retrieve.php",
    data: jQuery("#form1").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success:  function(data){
       $('#div1').html(data);
    }
});
```

Please, help. I need to print this data in tabular form in a div for Name & Email.

Comment: Do you really need help building a HTML table..?

Comment: I need to know how to put this json data in tabular format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a table? Something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "retrieve.php",
    data: jQuery("#form1").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success:  function(data){
       var html = '<table>';
       JSON.parse(data).forEach(function(item){ 
           html += '<tr><td>'+item.jname+'<td><td>'+item.jemail+'</td></tr>'; 
       });
       html += '</table>';
       $('#div1').html(html);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Put your JSON data into table rows, don’t forget the `<tbody>`:

```
var HTML = '';
var JSON = [{"jname":"Charles","jemail":"charles@gmail.com"},
            {"jname":"Bollen","jemail":"bollen@gmail.com"}];
JSON.forEach(function(person){
    HTML += '<tr><td>' + person.jname + '</td><td>' + person.jemail + '</td></tr>';
});
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<table><tbody>' + HTML + '</tbody></table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse that.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "retrieve.php",
data: jQuery("#form1").serialize(),
cache: false,
success:  function(data){
   var parse = JSON.parse(data);
   //then do what you are going to do.
   alert(parse.jname);
   alert(parse.jemail);
}
```